# How to skip certain migration files when using RefreshDatabase trait

Tags: mysql, laravel, sqlite

I am writing up some tests for my Laravel project.

My TestCase files use the RefreshDatabase trait which, to my knowledge, runs all my migrations every time a test is run.

I am using SQLite in my test environment and MySQL in my dev environment.

Now the problem is I have recently created a migration file which executes some raw MySQL code.

When I run my tests now, I get the following error

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "OR": syntax error`

It seems that SQLite does not support the CREATE OR REPLACE syntax (see my code below).

The migration file which is causing the problem merely creates a view table so it is not necessary for my tests (at least for the time being).

Possible Solutions?

I guess my main options are either of the following:

Use MySQL for testing environment

Skip over any migration file which executes MySQL code. But how?

Not that it should matter but this is the MySQL code which is causing the problem:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_projects
    AS
    SELECT
        projects.title AS title,
        projects.description AS description,
        _project_types.title AS type,
        _project_timelines.title AS projected_timeline,
        users.id AS manager_id,
        users.username AS manager_username,
        projects.planned_start_date AS start_date,
        projects.planned_end_date AS end_date
    FROM
        projects
        LEFT JOIN users ON projects.manager = users.id
        LEFT JOIN _project_types ON projects.type = _project_types.id
        LEFT JOIN _project_timelines ON projects.projected_timeline = _project_timelines.id;
");
```

Comment: It's not answer - but try this. It's fast as SQLIte, but moves out all problems like you have https://medium.com/@2618094/speed-up-feature-tests-in-laravel-with-docker-compose-and-tmpfs-a845a278d072

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your migrations file you would be able to test for which environment you are in. When running in `PHPunit` you app environment is `"testing"`.

So in your migration add the following. Using the `app()` helper to test which environment you are in. This will skip the migration, when running in the `testing` environment.

```
public function up() {
    if (app()->environment('testing')) {
        return ;
    }

    ... your code
}

public function down() {
    if (app()->environment('testing')) {
        return ;
    }

    ... your code
}
```